# How to disable control characters received with Expect.pm

Tags: perl, ssh, terminal, expect.pm

I am using Expect.pm to connect with SSH to a remote server.
While connected, I'm sending commands via the Expect object, and I receive answers from the remote server with it's control characters:

```
spawn id(22): Does `show \r\033[Kadmin@host> show log \r\033[Kadmin@host> show log config \r\033[Kadmin@host> show log config result \r\033[Kadmin@host> show log config result equal \r\033[Kadmin@host> show log config result equal succeeded\r\n\033[?1h\033=\033[@959;1H\033[K'
```

All these control characters are messing my pattern matching done with Expect.
My question is: How can I avoid seeing these control characters in the returning characters?

Comment: It looks like you are connecting to a networking device, provide as much information as possible aswell as the code that is producing the behaviour so that people can help you.

Comment: It is a PaloAlto Networks PanOS 6.0.7 FW device. It's problematic to show the code for this is a closed project, but let's assume this is a simple usage of creating new expect object, sending commands and matching the return traffic with the "-re" and regex parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems some of the control characters are coming from the PS1 environvement variable, try setting that to something different after you establish the ssh session. In bash that would be:

```
export PS1="dummy_prompt> "
```

It's also worth checking what kind of environvement you have with the below command

```
env
```